# How do i test that an inputted username and password is registered

Tags: html, authentication, online-game

I am creating an online game that required a signup. I am using a google form for the sign up and a google spreadsheet to store the data. I also have a login form, but no way to test that the inputted username and password is registered. Is there a way to test that it matches a login in the google spreadsheet?

code for login form:

```
<div id="container_demo">
<!-- hidden anchor to stop jump http://www.css3create.com/Astuce-Empecher-le-scroll-avec-l-utilisation-de-target#wrap4  -->
<a class="hiddenanchor" id="toregister"></a>
<a class="hiddenanchor" id="tologin"></a>
<div id="wrapper">
<div id="login" class="animate form">
   <form  action="mysuperscript.php" autocomplete="on">
      <h1 style="color:darkred">Log in</h1>
      <p> 
         <label for="username" class="uname" data-icon="u" style="color:darkred" > Your email or username </label>
         <input id="username" name="username" required="required" type="text" placeholder="eg. john.doe@mail.com"/>
      </p>
      <p> 
         <label for="password" class="youpasswd" data-icon="p" style="color:darkred"> Your password </label>
         <input id="password" name="password" required="required" type="password" placeholder="eg. johndoe123" /> 
      </p>
      <p class="login button"> 
         <input type="submit" value="Login" /> 
      </p>
   </form>
</div>
```

Comment: I know that this is not possible with Google Forms, but here is a gentle reminder: Don't store passwords in plaintext!

Comment: I embedded the code for you. In the future post the code on this site instead of on external links.

Answer (score 1):

I would strongly suggest to **not** use google forms to save user data. For various reasons.

**First (Privacy):** Google forms data belongs to Google. You are not the owner of the userdata.

**Second (Performance):** Each time a user does a login you must fetch the data out of the spreadsheet and further process it

**Third (Ease of use):** Except for a predefined form for user registration everything else get's more complicated. There are databases that are made for storing table like data (ms sql, mysql, postgresql). And even NoSQL databases outperform Google spreadsheets in all aspects.

I tell you that using a real database to store userdata is the better approach.

---

If you still wan't to use Google spreadsheets have a look at the [Spreadsheet API for PHP](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/quickstart/php) (Your login form action is a php script)

Comment: thank you for this information. but is there a way to do this on a chromebook?